# MongoDB adding `test` database while execution

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out why my `MongoDB` connection is not connecting me to a particular database.

My connection string is `mongodb://localhost:27017/`
Meanwhile, I'm trying to execute the script somehow it appends database `test`.

Here is my code from `env.ts`:

```
const PRIMARY_DB_URI = process.env.PRIMARY_DB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/'

credentials: PRIMARY_DB_URI + '?socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000'
```

connection.ts:

```
export const fortisConnection = mongoose.createConnection(
  database.credentials!
)
fortisConnection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log(mongoose.connections)
})
```

I need to extract data from `mongodb://localhost:27017/` but have such a log.

```
 name: 'test',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: undefined,
    pass: undefined,
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      topology: [Server],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
```

Field `name` states for `database name`.

When I'm trying to connect to a particular database like: `mongodb://localhost:27017/data`

It does not connect to database `data` and asks to return some users as shown below, it does not return anything.

script:

```
async function test() {
    try {
        const user = await User.find()
        console.log(1, ' USER: ', user)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(' error: ', e)
    }
}
```

Question: why it appends `test` to the database connection string?

Comment: Database `test` is the default if you don't specify any, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit please write it as an answer to mark it!